# Powershell to Identify machines with the same driver installed twice

Tags: powershell, zebra-printers

Looking to build a script to identify machines with the same driver installed on it. (and possibly a second script to identify driver version).

if a duplicate zebra driver gets installed on a machine it can cause problems.

```
    $servers = Get-Content 'c:\servers.txt'
ForEach($server in $servers) {
Get-WmiObject win32_printerdriver -ComputerName $server|` 
select  pscomputername,name | where name -Like "*zebra*"
Format-Table -AutoSize}
```

Above is what i have tried but I probably should have a second where clause for results greater than 1.

All help and advice appreciated.

As a secondary part to this question, if i wanted to check all machines in our organisation, would using the ADC module be the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach: the `$ZebraPrintersOnServer` object is always an array so that you can check its `Count` property:

```
$servers = Get-Content 'c:\servers.txt'
ForEach($server in $servers) {
    $ZebraPrintersOnServer = @(
        Get-WmiObject win32_printerdriver -ComputerName $server |
            Where-Object Name -Like "*zebra*"
    )
    switch ( $ZebraPrintersOnServer.Count ) {
        0 { # no Zebra printer found; 
            # mimic a "fake" $ZebraPrintersOnServer object
            $ZebraPrintersOnServer = @( 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    PSComputerName = $server;
                    Name = ''
                }
            )
            break
          }
        1 { # exactly one Zebra printer found
            # no action needed?
            break
          }
        default { # more than one Zebra printer found,
                  # do some action here
                  # on the $ZebraPrintersOnServer object?
                  break
                }
    }
    # general common output 
    $ZebraPrintersOnServer | Select-Object PSComputerName, Name
}
```

BTW: note that

- there is no *line continuation* backtick after a `|` pipeline operator, and
- final `Select-Object` or `Format-Table` is used merely for *human-legible* output.